# Given that n and m are integers, if $n^2 + 1 = 2m$, prove that m is the sum of the squares of 2 non-negative integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have absolutely no idea how to approach the question posed in the title, and would like a **hint** towards the answer. I tried multiple approaches, such as multiplying both sides by 2, or subtracting 2 from both sides to make the LHS a difference of squares, or adding $2n$ to both sides to make the LHS a perfect square. I had no idea how to progress by doing any of these methods, though.

Comment: Hint: $n$ must be odd.

Comment: $n$ is odd since $n^2 = 2m-1$ which is odd

Comment: Ah right, n must be odd was another thing I saw too. I don't know how to apply that to m must be the sum of 2 squares since the RHS is 2m, not just m. The right hand side must be even but I don't see how that helps me with the fact that m is the sum of 2 squares.

Comment: @user8594725 Write $n=2k+1$, expand the square, cancel a $2$, then look closely at what's left.

Comment: Another hint: Try small cases. For $ n = 1, 3, 5, 7, \ldots, $ what is the corresponding $m$? Is there a pattern to how we can write it as the sum of 2 squares?

Comment: Alright thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RHS is even, so the LHS must be even as well, and that happens only when $n$ is odd.

Expressing $n$ as $2k+1$, we get: $(2k+1)^2+1=2m$

$\implies 4k^2+4k+2=2m \implies 2k^2+2k+1=m \implies k^2+(k^2+2k+1)=m$

$\implies k^2+(k+1)^2=m$.

Comment: @useruser8594725  The problem statement is incorrect and ought to be changed to "...prove that m is the sum of the squares of two integers" (delete "non-negative"): e.g. for $k=-5,-4,$ the given equation remains true.

Comment: @RyanG in your example, $n$ seems to be $- 9$ and $m$ seems to be $41$.  In that case $m$ certainly is the sum of two squares of non-negative integers.  So the problem statement is not incorrect

Comment: @Henry Oh yes, the variable of interest here is $m,$ not $k,$ and $m$ *is* indeed expressible as the sum of two natural numbers—regardless of that fact that it need not be expressed as such.  Thanks!